# Как строки таблицы занести массив?

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно занести три последние строки в массив из таблицы бд, каким образом это можно сделать?

```
include('connections/trooble.php');
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY (`id`) DESC LIMIT 3");
$r = mysql_fetch_array($q);
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
    $n[] = $r['news'];
}

$i = 0;
while ($i < 3) {
    $a = $n[$i];
    $i++;

    echo $a;
}
```

Вроде все правильно, но не выводит самую первую новость.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если верно понял то:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY (`id`) DESC LIMIT 3");
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    //Result of the array
}
```

Comment: "//Result of the massif" - О_о  почему "massif" а не "array" ?))

Comment: Изменил на array если так глаз лучше воспринимает)

Comment: array привычнее)))

Answer (score 0):

```
$r = mysql_fetch_array($q);
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
    $n[] = $r['news'];
}
```

вот здесь по моему первая строка лишная.... 
получается так что два раз подряд делается фетч но после первого на массив на пишится. 
Извините за мой плохой русский.